# Android link open app - can I get the referal?

Tags: android

Let's say my app is Instagram.
Every link open for website [www.instagram.com/username](http://www.instagram.com/username) from **google search** on Chrome on android will open the app on that username.

Can I get the **referral** application/website - without having modified URL (can't force google url)?
I want to know where it came from (should be chrome + google search)

Can Instagram know where the link been clicked ?